# Is there a word for a linear combination where the coefficients are nonnegative

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

This is a terminology question. If I have real numbers $a_1, \dots, a_n$ that are nonnegative and sum to 1, then the expression
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i
$$
would either be called a *mixture* or a *convex combination* of $x_1, \dots, x_n$. (The $x_i$ need to be such that this expression makes sense - they could be vectors, for example, or probability distributions.)

On the other hand, if $a_1, \dots, a_n$ don't have to sum to 1 and don't have to be nonnegative, then the same expression would be called a *linear combination* of $x_1, \dots, x_n$.

My question is, what would it be called if the $a_i$ do have to be nonnegative but don't have to sum to 1?

One could always say "linear combination with nonnegative coefficients", but that's a bit of a mouthful. I could shorten it to "nonnegative linear combination", but that's awkward because it's not really the linear combination that's nonnegative. "Conical combination" would also make sense (by analogy to "convex combination"), because the set of all such combinations forms a convex cone, but I don't think I've ever seen anyone use that. So I'm wondering if there's a more common term.

If there is a common term, is there also a word to express that at least one coefficient is nonzero?

Comment: Wikipedia says that this is called a [conical combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination). (If the coefficients sum to 1, but don't have to be nonnegative, it's called an [affine combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_combination).) See [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination#Affine,_conical,_and_convex_combinations), for the various names and conditions on the coefficients.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn feel free to post that as an answer so I can accept it, if you care about that sort of thing.

Comment: Despite the awkwardness, I have commonly seen this referred to as a *non-negative linear combination*. The phrase *positive linear combination* is also used, referring to the "interior" of the cone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, a linear combination where all the coefficients are nonnegative is called a [conical combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination). [This table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination#Affine,_conical,_and_convex_combinations) describes the various conditions on the coefficients for affine, conical, and convex combinations.